# What is ForwardRenderer in Qt 5.5's Qt3D examples?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.5, qt3d

[Assimp example of Qt3d of Qt 5.5 uses ForwardRenderer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-assimp-main-qml.html).

I copied the code, and in `main.qml` QtCreator shows red line under that name indicating unknown component. Clicking on that word does not take me anywhere.

The program is compiling without any errors, and shows only a blue window when run.

**What is ForwardRenderer?** Why is the red line there?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are forward renderer files on Qt site:

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qt3d-dynamicscene-cpp-forwardrenderer-H.html

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qt3d-dynamicscene-cpp-forwardrenderer-cpp.html

Here is the explanation from KDAB what is FrameGraph and how it deals with Forward Renderer: http://www.kdab.com/qt3d-2-0-framegraph/

> ForwardRenderer is not a FrameGraph Node type in itself. It is a default FrameGraph tree implementation for a forward renderer provided as a convenience for users.

## Update: Recreate it manually

By inspecting the C++ I was able to recreate `ForwardRenderer` entirely in QML

```
    // FwdRenderer.qml
    RenderSettings {
        id: forward
        property Camera camera: null
        activeFrameGraph: TechniqueFilter {
            matchAll: [ FilterKey { name: "renderingStyle"; value: "forward" } ]
            RenderSurfaceSelector{
                Viewport {
                    normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0,0,1,1)
                    CameraSelector{
                        camera: forward.camera
                        ClearBuffers{
                            buffers: ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer
                            clearColor: Qt.rgba(1.0,0,0,0.1)
                        }
                        FrustumCulling{
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This was in fact, kind of cool. The new type `FwdRenderer` can act as a drop-in replacement of `ForwardRenderer`. It helped me a lot in understanding the Framegraph, hope it helps.

And by the way, the red line is a bug in that version of Qt Creator. It shouldn't be marked as an error.